# Using TS generic parameter default value for React component prop breaks autocomplete for this prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, enums, autocomplete

There is a `Button` component with an `s | m` size and `m` by default.

There are different icon components, each has from one to four sizes of `xs | s | m | l`, no default.

`Button` takes an icon component as a prop, validating that it corresponds to its *current* size, otherwise there should be an error. If no size is set explicitly for `Button`, an icon must have `m` size (at least).

```js
/** Icon.types.ts */

type TIcon<TIconSize extends string> = (props: {
  size: TIconSize
  // ...
}) => JSX.Element


/** Button.types.ts */

type TButtonSize = 's' | 'm'

type TButtonProps<TSize extends TButtonSize> = {
  size?: TSize
  Icon?: TIcon<NoInfer<TSize>>
  // ...
}


/** Button.tsx */

const Button = <TSize extends TButtonSize = 'm'>({
  size = 'm' as TSize,
  Icon,
  // ...
}: TButtonProps<TSize>) => { ... }
```

Everything works perfectly, except one nasty **but** — autocomplete suggests only the generic default value for `size` prop:

[Icon with `m` size fits the button of `m` or no explicit size and doesn't fit the one with `s` size. Autocomplete for the button's size prop suggests `m` option only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbTrA.jpg)

*(I have not enough reputation to post an image, so here's a link only, sorry)*

ps. Yeah yeah, I know that using a default value in destructuring with a generic type is not recommended. But in this case, the component won't be called as a function with some conflicting explicit generic value `Button<'s'>()`. Thus, this little typecast trick is completely safe. Moreover, it has nothing to do with the issue. I've tried a lot of variations in an attempt to find the root of troubles, including not using the default value of the prop itself — it has no effect.

##### What have I done with it and what am I expecting?

Fortunately, I was able to find a solution... empirically hehe. Somehow enum nullifies the problem:

```js
enum ButtonSize {
  default = 'm',
}

const Button = <TSize extends TButtonSize = ButtonSize.default>({
  size = ButtonSize.default as TSize,
  Icon,
  // ...
}: TButtonProps<TSize>) => { ... }
```

As long as the issue is valid for both VSCode and WebStorm, I assume it's not an IDE-specific bug, but rather some kind of TS caveat-by-design I neither understand nor have been able to find an explanation for anywhere.

So, this post is not about the question of how to make things work (although it would be nice to get rid of the enum workaround), but rather a kind request for someone to explain what is going on here :) What causes the original problem, and why does such a solution work?

Comment: pps. Just in case, more info on NoInfer — [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).
Usually an inferred type value is used in some kind of condition, but not for _typing_ some other value. So, with just `Icon?: TIcon<TSize>` in my case the size of `Icon` was inferred alongside the size of `Button` (and resulting type was an intersection of both)  
This approach helps to fix things.